# mysqlbinlog: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/' (Errcode: 21)

Tags: mysql

i have this error when try to download the binary log from my mysql server instance (RDS), tha command is:

```
mysqlbinlog --read-from-remote-server --host=my.server.rds.amazonaws.com --port=3306  --user foo --password --result-file=/tmp/ mysql-bin-changelog.164974
```

Comment: i have tried to write also to /home directory...i launch this command from root user

Comment: I tried to /home/ec2-user with root user and have same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_result-file) (or `man mysqlbinlog`):

> --result-file=name, -r name
>
> Without the --raw option, this option indicates the file to which
>   mysqlbinlog writes text output. With --raw, mysqlbinlog writes one
>   binary output file for each log file transferred from the server,
>   writing them by default in the current directory using the same names
>   as the original log file. In this case, the --result-file option value
>   is treated as a prefix that modifies output file names.

So you should add a file name, for example `out.txt`:

```bash
mysqlbinlog --read-from-remote-server --host=my.server.rds.amazonaws.com --port=3306  --user foo --password --result-file=/tmp/out.txt mysql-bin-changelog.164974
```